# Forecasting ar(p) for several counties

Tags: time-series, forecasting, panel-data, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have a data set of prices, these prices vary across time and across area. I have 18 areas with 32 time periods.

What i want to do is forecast these prices, i have found that a AR(3) process fits the data for each area using first difference.
\begin{equation}
\Delta \hat{y}_t = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 \Delta y_{t-1} + \hat{\beta}_1 \Delta y_{t-2}+ \hat{\beta}_1 \Delta y_{t-3} + \epsilon_t
\end{equation}

I have been told to investigate panel data methods, however the information i find about dynamic panel data methods requires "large" amount of time series observations (32 not really "large").

My concern is for the latent heterogeneity, assuming prices in one area affects other/neighboring areas, over time.

How should my estimation be done when the ultimate goal is forecasting the individual area prices. I have considered several estimation methods, but lack specific knowledge about how to select the best.

Estimation methods considered:

- DPD (dynamic panel data)
- SUR (Seemingly unrelated regression)
- SAR (spatial autoregressive models)

Comment: Why don't you try a VAR(p) model?

Comment: Thank you! I had not considered this, from the brief description on wikipedia it seems to fit the description i have given.

Comment: There is a very good package `vars` which has implemented the VAR(p) conceps.

Comment: Yes, R. I am going to implement this in to my studies this coming semester, however my prefered statistical software as of now is Stata, which handles VAR(p) very well. Now, to VAR. Reading in "Greene - Econometric analysis" the difference between SUR and VAR(p) is that var uses identical number of lagged values for the exogenous variables. From this i can see that iff one of my areas has a AR(2) process instead of an AR(3) process, while the others have AR(3) VAR(p) is not suitable.

Comment: Then you will get an insignificant coefficient. Or, if you want, you can set some coefficients equal zero with the argument `restrictions` in the `vars` package.